# microsoft Dynamics's discovery.svc

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web, microsoft-dynamics

I want to connect to microsoft dynamics CRM via tools or code, but every time I try I get this error :

> the provided uri did not return any service endpoints

Also when I go to its discovery.svc link I get the following error :

> An error has occurred. 
>   Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics CRM Administrator. Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support.

I check the IIS binding and its just bind to 5555 for HTTP and 5556 for HTTPS and also the above error occur on server side too, I mean when I go to `http://myAddress:5555/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc` both in server and clients I get the error. I cant find any thing that could solve my problem in the internet and I'm stock in this simple problem for several days.

Comment: please post the code you are using for the connection

Comment: @GuidoPreite as I said I use tools like XrmToolBox and for the code I try to connect with microsoft sample codes that are in sdk. There is nothing wrong with code or software because they are from microsoft and ... I think it is a server side problem.

Comment: You might double check the link on the Developer Resources page (under Settings, then Customizations, then Developer Resoruces).  We have CRM installed on a port other than the default and when I was new to this organization that tripped me up at first.

Comment: @RobertM. Thanks for your comment but it was my proxy problem, I create a app.config file and paste following lines in it:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy >
     </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
Then it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think after I solved my problem this could be useful for somebody. There was two problem first my server has configuration problem and server needs restart to free its memory. so it's not bad if you check how memory you are using, and if its possible restart the server.

and after that I have a proxy problem that could be fix with creating a file name app.config and writing this lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
    <system.net> 
         <defaultProxy > 
         </defaultProxy>
   </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Then it'll works fine